# Cassandra cluster - Store equal data among the nodes

Tags: cassandra

In Cassandra Cluster, how can we ensure all nodes are having almost equal data, instead one node has more data, another has very less.

If this scenario occurs, what are the best practices

Thanks

Comment: If you provide the output of `nodetool status`, it will give additional context for those responding to your question. Cheers!

Comment: You might want to have a look at your partition key. partition key decides where your data goes

Comment: to me the main thing is to make sure that there is enough variability in your primary key (but not too much). Your primary key is hashed and the partition key is then used to assign the data to a node. Also partitions are NOT split across nodes. So, if a lot of your data has the same primary key then that data will all be stored on the same node. This is also called a hotspot.

Answer (score 0):

It is ok to expect a slight variation of 5-10%. The most common causes are the distribution of your partitions may not be truly random (more partitions on some nodes) and there may be a large variation in the size of the partitions (smallest partition is a few kilobytes but largest partition is 2GB).

There are also 2 other possible scenarios to consider.

**SINGLE-TOKEN CLUSTER**

If the tokens are not correctly calculated, some nodes may have a larger token range compared to others. Use the [token generation tool](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/configuration/configGenTokens.html) to get a list of tokens that is correctly distributed around the ring.

If the cluster is deployed with DataStax Enterprise, the easiest way is to [rebalance your cluster with OpsCenter](http://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/6.0/opsc/online_help/opscRebalanceCluster.html).

**VNODES CLUSTER**

Confirm that you have allocated the same number of tokens in `cassandra.yaml` with the `num_tokens` directive.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using ByteOrderedPartitioner for your cluster that should not happen. See DataStax documentation [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.x/cassandra/architecture/archPartitionerAbout.html) for more information about available partitioners and why it should not (normally) happen.